# Android Studio Git Add throwing error

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

I'm trying to add the current state of my project to my local Git index by using  VCS -> Git -> + Add, but I get the following message whenever I try to upload:

```
Throwable: Repository not found for root C:\Users\*******\Desktop\******\AndroidProjects\*****\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi (3 minutes ago)
```

What am I missing here?